# Mail Script in Rules

Tags: applescript, mail.app, mail-rules

Hopefully, I can explain what I am attempting to achieve. I have an email address designated for SMS (sms@domain.com) This account gets check via Mail (apple V13). I have a rule that every message does an Applescript as follows:

```
    using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages newMessages
        repeat with newMessage in newMessages
            tell application "Mail"
                set theText to ""
                set theSubject to ""
                repeat with theMessage in selectedMessages
                    set theText to theText & (content of theMessage) as string
                    set theSubject to theSubject & (subject of theMessage) as string                    
                    tell application "Messages"
                        activate --steal focus
                        set targetBuddy to theSubject
                        set targetService to id of service "SMS"
                        set textMessage to theText
                        set theBuddy to buddy targetBuddy of service id targetService
                        send textMessage to theBuddy
                    end tell
                end repeat
            end tell
        end repeat
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Unfortunately it does not work and for the life of me I dont understand why.
Could I ask for some assistance?

Comment: You've got a _Messages_ `tell` block inside a _Mail_ `tell` block, which is going to be  a potential cause for problems.  I'd suggest taking it outside the entire `on perform mail action` handler, and sticking it in its own handler that you can call.  I can't say for sure that it's definitely the source of your problem, but you also don't say anything about _how_ this script fails to work, i.e. what should it do, what does it do currently, and what errors arise and where in the script do they occur, etc. etc.

Comment: Ah: **`repeat with theMessage in selectedMessages`** This references the variable `selectedMessages`, which does not appear anywhere else in the script, so either this isn't the entire script, or this variable hasn't been declared/defined.

Comment: Thank you @CJK. I am very green in this space and I appreciate the help. I am attempting to activate this rule (with mail rules for every message) to run the script to do the following: Take the information from the email received and send an Imessage. (which works if run independently) the issue I find is it is not running it with the rule in place.

Comment: using terms from application "Mail"
 on perform mail action with messages TheMessages for rule theRule
  repeat with aMessage in TheMessages
   tell application "Mail"
    set theText to ""
    set theSubject to ""
    set theText to theText & (content of theMessage) as string
    set theSubject to theSubject & (subject of theMessage) as string

Comment: end tell
  end repeat
 end perform mail action with messages
 tell application "Messages"
  activate --steal focus
  set targetBuddy to theSubject
  set targetService to id of service "SMS"
  set textMessage to theText
  set theBuddy to buddy targetBuddy of service id targetService
  send textMessage to theBuddy
 end tell
end using terms from